# Не работает форма обратной связи на сайте

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

На сайте `maxg5.ru` есть форма обратной связи.
Код формы такой
**HTML:**

```
<div id="inline">
<form id="contact" action="#" method="post" name="contact">
<p>Имя<span>*</span></p>
<input id="name" class="txt" name="name" type="name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
<p>Телефон<span>*</span></p>
<input id="phone" class="txt phone" name="phone" type="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон">
<p>E-mail<span>*</span></p>
<input id="email" class="txt" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Ваш e-mail">
<p>Комментарий или сообщение<span>*</span></p>
<textarea id="msg" class="txtarea" name="msg" placeholder="Ваше сообщение:"></textarea>
<button id="send">Оставить заявку</button>
</form>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
function validateEmail(email) { 
var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]
{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
return reg.test(email);
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".modalbox").fancybox();
jQuery("#contact").submit(function() {return false;});
jQuery("#send").on("click", function() {
var emailval = jQuery("#email").val();
var namevl = jQuery("#name").val();
var phonevl = jQuery("#phone").val();
var msgval = jQuery("#msg").val();
var msglen = msgval.length;
var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);
if(mailvalid == false) {
  jQuery("#email").addClass("error");
 }
else if(mailvalid == true) {
  jQuery("#email").removeClass("error");
 }
if(mailvalid == false) {
  jQuery("#name").addClass("error");
 }
else if(mailvalid == true){
  jQuery("#name").removeClass("error");
 }
if(mailvalid == false) {
  jQuery("#phone").addClass("error");
 }
else if(mailvalid == true){
  jQuery("#phone").removeClass("error");
 }
if(msglen < 4) {
  jQuery("#msg").addClass("error");
 }
else if(msglen >= 4){
  jQuery("#msg").removeClass("error");
 }
if(mailvalid == true && msglen >= 4) {
// если обе проверки пройдены
// сначала мы скрываем кнопку отправки
$("#send").replaceWith("<em>отправка...</em>");
 jQuery.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: '/php/sendmessage.php',
 data: jQuery("#contact").serialize(),
  success: function(data) {
  if(data == "true") {
   jQuery("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
   jQuery(this).before("<p><strong>Ваше сообщение отправлено</strong></p>");
   setTimeout("jQuery.fancybox.close()", 1000);
   });
  }
  }
  });
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
// Обязательно измените e-mail на свой
$sendto = "maxg5@yandex.ru";
$usermail = $_POST['email'];
$username = $_POST['name'];
$userphone = $_POST['phone'];
$content = nl2br($_POST['msg']);
// Формирование заголовка письма
$subject = "Новое сообщение";
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";
// Формирование тела письма
$msg = "<html-->";
$msg .= "<h2 style="font-weight:bold">Новое сообщение</h2>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Имя:</strong> ".$username."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Номер телефона:</strong> ".$userphone."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Почта:</strong> ".$usermail."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Сообщение:</strong> ".$content."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "";
// отправка сообщения
if(@mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
?>
```

Но при нажатии на кнопку **Отправить** ничего не происходит.
В консоле есть такая ошибка:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /
```

Может ли из за этого форма не работает? Если да, то как эту ошибку исправить?

Comment: ну написано же - ошибка в регулярном выражении вашем. `var reg` Может стоит его взять в кавычки?

Comment: Не понял. Взять в кавычки значение var reg или само var reg? Там такой код: `var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]
{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;` Как правильно взять в кавычки?

Comment: значение переменной возьмите в кавычки